# How can I deploy a nodeJs application on wix.com

Tags: node.js, velo

I currently develop website using nodeJs for backend and HTML, CSS, Js for frontend.

I normally deploy my applications on Heroku, but it happens that the client already has a subscription to wix.com (which I am new to) and cannot change his host. He would like to keep his subscription on Wix.

Is there a way to upload my work to Wix, without having to redo all the work done in HTML, CSS, JS and NodeJs?

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly found a way to achieve that.
Wix have section that allow user to embedded external website on page section.

My solution:

- develop you web app and deploy it on heroku
- use heroku website's link on wix to embedded it